# Single Chars of an ID to String

Tags: c

Following code-snippet:

```
 unsigned char * get_id(unsigned char *buffer)
 {
     unsigned int i;

     for(i=0; i<8;i++)
         buffer[i] = read_byte(); // Returns uint8_t

     return buffer;
 }
```

At the end i have a 64-bit ID. I would like to call get_id() and to print the return value(ID) with printf. How do I do that?

My solution is:

```
unsigned char tmp_buf[8]; 
unsigned char *ptr;

ptr = get_id(tmp_buf);
printf("ID = %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x\n", ptr[7], ptr[6], ptr[5]...);
```

That is quite awful and I don' like it much, but how to print it in "one" small printf-statement?

Comment: Why not just use a loop?

Comment: why not write a function print_id(unsigned char *buffer) containing your printf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just print it as a 64-bit integer. You won't even need to byteswap anything.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>

union {
    uint8_t buf[8];
    uint64_t val;
} buffer;

uint8_t *ptr = get_id(buffer.buf);
assert(ptr && "should get id");
printf("ID = %"PRIx64"\n", buffer.val);
```